# Database not update doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

why I can't update database in my server?
This commit work in local server.
Help please, I do not already know where to look

```
icc-> php app/console doctrine:schema:update
PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Warning: require_once(/home/icc/web/icc.kdpu.edu.ua/public_html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /home/icc/web/icc.kdpu.edu.ua/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:236
Stack trace:
#0 /home/icc/web/icc.kdpu.edu.ua/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php(236): Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'require_once(/h...', '/home/icc/web/i...', 236, Array)
#1 /home/icc/web/icc.kdpu.edu.ua/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php(236): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::getAllClassNames()
#2 /home/icc/web/icc.kdpu.edu.ua/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php(128): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\Anno in /home/icc/web/icc.kdpu.edu.ua/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php on line 236
PHP Fatal error:  Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::getAllClassNames(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/icc/web/icc.kdpu.edu.ua/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php on line 236


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Compile Error: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver:
  :getAllClassNames(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/share
  /pear:/usr/share/php')
```

Comment: The problem was that I had essentially unnecessary in the folder after removing all good.
Folder: `src/AppBundle/Entity`

Comment: So you've answered this question yourself? Is that correct?

Comment: @johnny, yes. I solved problem just delete not necessary files.